# Did this crack develop from cowl panel removal?

Tags: windshield

About a week ago I removed the cowl/scuttle panel for cleaning under the area.  In the process I used a flat head to pick some clips up and when putting the cowl back due to bonnet being in may way I reAlly struggled and wrestled the cowl
Back into place.

A week later I now have a massive crack hive staffs from under the cowl panel and goes into spreads into the world screen as you can see(not all lines visible).  In the second pic just before cowl panel you can see cracks going in.

1. Was this damage likely to be caused by cowl repair. What would have caused it?

- I don’t remember the flathead making contact with glass, it was quite easy to remove the clips
- I do remember wrestling and hearing noises while trying and to put the plastic panel back in.  But would the plastic panel even if it slammed into the glass at times have caused this?

2. How can I avoid this.  Is the correct way to move the hood or is there a way to smoothly put the panel in place with hood on(assuming plastic panel agitation caused this)?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would not blame the cowl, but a poor operator could be the cause.

Comment: @Solar Mike what do you mean by a poor operator?  Do you mean I(the operator) was handling the cowl poorly and scratched the screen?  Or do you mean the wipers have not been reinstalled properly and they’re putting pressure on the screen or what is it?  Thanks.

Comment: You can usually trace a crack back to its origin. If i'm seeing it correctly, in the 2nd picture, the two cracks seem to come together under the windshield wiper. This seems to be pointing at the origin. All it would take is a scratch at the tip of the windshield to cause a stress riser, which would inflict the crack. It just takes a little stress in the right place and boom, Jake's your daddy. The scratch could be cause from anything, like a badly place metal tool.

Comment: @Paulster2. Exactly.  The origin is going to under the cowl.  I have already lifted the cowland I can see that’s where it started and this is where I recently did a repair.  The question is can the banging plastic cowl I was wrestling to fit in cause it or would it have been the flat head which to my knowledge didn’t touch the glass?  Thanks.

Comment: If hit just right at the very edge I could see the cowl doing it.

Comment: go to an auto glass repair shop. ask them to see what can make a windscreen crack. you'll be surprised.