# How to fit cowl panel smoothly?

Tags: body-work

Civic coupe vti 1999.

When fitting a cowl panel, as the bonnet was in the way, I really struggled to fit it in smoothly and instead forced/snapped it into place.  In the process I believe I caused my windscreen to crack with the cowl panel hitting the lower edge of the windshield ([Did this crack develop from cowl panel removal?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/80430/did-this-crack-develop-from-cowl-panel-removal)).

I could have removed the bonnet then did the job which would have let the cowl fit smoothly.  But I think it should be possible to fit the cowl smoothly without removing the bonnet.

Is there a right way to push the cowl into place without wrestling and smacking the windscreen as I did, if so how?

Thanks.

Comment: On more modern Civics, you first remove a few small plastic pieces at each end so you can pull the plastic cover off the screen wiper holding nuts and remove the wipers. Then remove the clips at the ends and the one in the middle at the front of the main panel. Then you press the panel down at the back (nearest the windscreen) to release the plastic hooks that hold it at the back and pull it forwards. Then tilt it up at the front so you can remove the plumbing for the screen washer nozzles. It should then just lift out. I don't know if the old models were different.

Comment: ... I guess if you had to use brute force, you were fighting against the clips at the back (which are probably the main fastening points when they click into place) instead of releasing them by pushing down.